# What changes is required from Web Application to act as a service provider in SAML 2.0?

Tags: service, integration, saml-2.0, provider

I have been reading up on SAML 2.0 and its implementation, but so far I have not found any materials regarding this area on integrating with a web application.

I want to know what are the changes required on the web application (ie. www.my-app.com) so that when a user enters this URL, it will be re-routed to the service provider to generate the SAMLRequest and etc and communicates with the IdP.

Secondly, when the IdP sends the SAMLResponse back to SP (Assertion Consumer Service), How does the SP provide the results of the response back to the web application?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The question is confusing. You ask "to act as a service provider" and then you ask "the SP provide the results of the response back to the web application". So do you want the web application to act as a SP or is the SP separate? Also, why is there a SP? Why can't your app. communicate directly with the IDP?

Comment: To clarify, the web application is the protected resource. In this scenario, it is likely to have multiple protected resources within the SP. So does it mean that I will need to configure multiple SPs fronting each of this protected resources?

Answer (score 0):

"the web application is the protected resource" and you want to use SAML as the protocol.

To do this, you have to have a SAML client side stack for your application. Refer: [SAML : SAML connectivity / toolkit](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013/06/saml-saml-connectivity-toolkit.html)

Is the application .NET, Java ... ?

The other alternative is to use an intermediate SP as a bridge. Most IDP can also run as SP and they support both WS-Fed and SAML. So you could go in as WS-Fed and out as SAML.

No, you can have one SP and connect multiple applications to it.

Comment: Okay.. This application will be in Java. Do you have any reference materials with regards to "you can have one SP and connect multiple applications to it."? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is great when looking at architectures for being a Service Provider (SP) to request a security token.  The choice of protocol is important.  If you want to be a cloud vendor, SAML is the current leading and most supported protocol. If this is for an on-premise integration and your technology stack is .NET, then WS-Federation (which contains SAML) is another choice for protocol.

You also inquired, How does the SP provide the results of the response back to the web application?  In the world of federation, each web application manages its own session generally through some implementation of HTTP session cookie.  The SSO IdP server has a session cookie, as well as your SP web application would have its own session cookie.  Upon receipt of the SAMLResponse, your application would validate the SAML (e.g. digital certificate, issuer, audience, etc).  If valid it would read the "subject" and any attributes and then create the HTTP session cookie for your application. If you are using some type of container based security model, the "subject" can be asserted to the container, or your application can read the HTTP session cookie, or you can implement your own security model.

Comment: It will likely have a SP application in between the IdP and web application that handles the SAMLRequest/SAMLResponse and from there onward, return the results to the web application to create its own security context. In this case, the web application has to be modified to cater for processing of the result for the ("subject") and any other attributes coming from the SP application.

Comment: There are many commercial vendor implementations for having a SP Server Role to handle the SAMLRequest/SAMLResponse protocol. I work with PingFederate frequently that does have a SP Server role.In order to get what is referred to as last mile integration to the web application after PingFederate has processed the SAMLResponse, there are a couple of options, one is referred to as an agentless reference ID, which is a set of REST calls to receive the identity into your Java application.  The other is a Java Agent that uses a PingFederate OpenToken to move the subject into your Java application.

Comment: To follow on from previous comment... from within your application, you read the "subject" and then assert the session.  Both agentless reference ID and Java Agent can move the subject plus any attributes that come from the SAML token.

Comment: Thanks Eric! Good to heard that there is such a role, SP Server Role which is what I am looking for. Is the agentless reference ID concept available online?

Comment: All the ping information is available on their website.  In particular the Agentless Kit for their technology is on their [download page](https://www.pingidentity.com/en/products/downloads.html).